# How to wipe dirt away from glass? Unity3D

Tags: textures, paint, erase, unity-game-engine

I need to wipe away dirt from a pane of glass. I was thinking I could change the texture at the area where I wiped, or the dirt could be a separate object that gets destroyed to reveal clean glass, but I can't figure out how to do either of those without changing the entire pane of glass at once.

Comment: put a 2nd gameobject like 0.001 units (just enough so you have no zfighting) above the pane and put the dirt on that. then manipulate its alpha values where your finger is.

Answer (score 1):

Look into writing a shader that takes takes a clean texture, a dirty texture, and a third texture to lerp between the clean and dirty texture.

You will need draw the third texture on the cpu using `Texture2D.SetPixel()` & `Texture2D.GetPixel()` and make the pixels around the finger darker based on distance.